# Error "acl connection already exists" when reconnect an iphone via bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am developing a Bluetooth device based on bluez5.37 on linux3.14. But I have met a problem recently. The problem is that when I reconnect an iPhone from the device after disconnecting manually, sometimes I will get the error of "acl connection already exists", which will lead to I couldn't connect to the iPhone for about 20~30s. The following are the HCI logs.

```
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 12                      13:00:31.348207
  L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 15 len 4
    Destination CID: 57866
    Source CID: 67
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 12                      13:00:31.350325
  L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 16 len 4
    Destination CID: 57609
    Source CID: 66
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 7                       13:00:31.420332
  Channel: 56840 len 3 [PSM 25 mode 0] {chan 1}
  AVDTP: Close (0x08) Command (0x00) type 0x00 label 7 nosp 0
    ACP SEID: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          13:00:31.455746
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 1
    Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 12                      13:00:31.455757
  L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 15 len 4
    Destination CID: 57866
    Source CID: 67
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 12                      13:00:31.455759
  L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 16 len 4
    Destination CID: 57609
    Source CID: 66
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          13:00:31.456883
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 1
    Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 6                       13:00:31.529352
  Channel: 65 len 2 [PSM 25 mode 0] {chan 1}
  AVDTP: Close (0x08) Response Accept (0x02) type 0x00 label 7 nosp 0
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 12                      13:00:31.530186
  L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 17 len 4
    Destination CID: 57351
    Source CID: 64
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 12                      13:00:31.677224
  L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 17 len 4
    Destination CID: 57351
    Source CID: 64
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          13:00:31.678608
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 1
    Count: 1
< ACL Data TX: Handle 1 flags 0x00 dlen 12                      13:00:33.042869
  L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 18 len 4
    Destination CID: 56840
    Source CID: 65
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5          13:00:33.123297
    Num handles: 1
    Handle: 1
    Count: 1
> HCI Event: Link Supervision Timeout Changed (0x38) plen 4     13:00:33.195809
    Handle: 1
    Timeout: 20000.000 msec (0x7d00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 1 flags 0x02 dlen 12                      13:00:33.197025
  L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 18 len 4
    Destination CID: 56840
    Source CID: 65
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                  13:00:34.041874
    Handle: 1
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                       13:00:34.050356
  Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                  13:00:34.120562
    Status: Success (0x00)
    Handle: 1
    Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ Device Disconnected: 28:F0:76:F0:3B:3F (0) reason 2
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13          13:00:35.647186
    Address: 28:F0:76:F0:3B:3F (Apple, Inc.)
    Packet type: 0xcc18
      DM1 may be used
      DH1 may be used
      DM3 may be used
      DH3 may be used
      DM5 may be used
      DH5 may be used
    Page scan repetition mode: R1 (0x01)
    Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
    Clock offset: 0xa75a
    Role switch: Allow slave (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                       13:00:35.655129
  Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) ncmd 1
    Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11                    13:00:36.987592
    Status: ACL Connection Already Exists (0x0b)
    Handle: 1
    Address: 28:F0:76:F0:3B:3F (Apple, Inc.)
    Link type: ACL (0x01)
    Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
@ Connect Failed: 28:F0:76:F0:3B:3F (0) status 0x09
```

I have been confused by this problem for weeks, and no progress is made till now. Could anyone provide some advices. Thanks.

PS: The cpu is IMX6 and the blueooth chip is ti wl1837

Comment: You should add the text instead of an image. The text in the images cannot be indexed.

Comment: Thank you jww, I have added the text instead of the image.